# Use Tridion and Markdown

Tags: sdl-tridion

Hi fellow content developers,

We use Tridion CMS and XMetal authoring tools for developing content for user's guide. And use Markdown and Stoplight to edit and publish API guides. Is there a way we can replace XMetal with Markdown and use Tridion CMS for developing user's guides? Our user's guide are translated. Please suggests.

Comment: Could you clarify if this is Tridion Sites or Tridion Docs? One is a Web CMS, the other is a Component CMS, and from your description and use case it sounds like it’s Docs, but can you enlighten us please?

Comment: Yes, it's Tridio Docs.